# Storyboards, UITabBarController and SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios

I have a storyboard that uses a UITabBarController with 3 tabs.
I want to use SWRevealViewController to add the sliding menu functionality.
Opening the menu will slide the hole UITabBarController.

Did anyone managed to implement this kind of behaviour with storyboards UITabBarController and SWRevealViewController?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to integrate it. Below are the steps to do it:

1. Add a new UIViewController to the storyboard.
2. Remove the content view from the newly added UIViewController
3. Make sure "Is Initial View Controller" is checked in IB for the newly added UIViewController
4. Set the custom class for the newly added UIViewController to SWRevealViewController
5. Connect it to a view controller that you intend to be the rear view controller - give the segue "sw_rear" identifier in IB. This must be a reveal controller segue type.
6. Connect it to the UITabBarController - give the segue "sw_front" identifier in IB. This must be a reveal controller segue type.

Comment: I believe this worked for me as well.  That is, I have a tabbar / navigation controller app that I did the above 6 steps for and now my app runs fine - as though nothing changed.  ie., I don't see the little icon in the top left of my front controller and no swipe gestures work so I can't tell that I have a reveal controller involved at all.  How do I expose the revealcontroller's icon?

Comment: You have to handle opening the reveal yourself.

Comment: It's not necessary, but it would make this answer really great if you added a quick example of opening the reveal in at the end. That'd be complete to anyone familiar with the library.

Comment: I follow this steps, but when I run my app it only show a "sw_front"view controler.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a navigation controller before tab bar controller(sw_front > navigation controller > tab bar controller).

Answer (score 0):

gfdx answered his own question, but make sure to also look at [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) for more insight on how to hook up everything else correctly.

Because I'm using Core Data and I was told that calling

```
[[NSApp delegate]managedObjectContext];
```

is not a good idea, I pass in my data controller class to the views in `AppDelegate.m`. Since I'm now using the `SWRevealViewController` instead of my subclass of `UITabBarController`, I had to make some modifications.

`SWRevealViewController` performs some interesting behaviors on load, one of which is loading the dependent view controllers by calling the segues. Be aware that if you make changes in your subclassed `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, make sure to always, always call the super's method, otherwise you'll end up with a black, blank application.